# how to use amazon rds with cpanel

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, cpanel, amazon-rds

I have cpanel instance on AWS cloud created with cpanel/whm ami. Now I'm using mysql on same server. Now planning to use with RDS for Database. Currently I have only one domain (wordpress website ) and 25 email accounts.

Comment: Spin up a RDS. Point your applications (WordPress) at the RDS. Nothing to do with cPanel.

Comment: You mean configure database as rds on wp-config. is there any way to use mailservices like roundcube use rds ?

Comment: Ditch cPanel and configure Roundcube that way yourself. These sorts of things are why cPanel is a pain in the ass to admin and off-topic on ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link:

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/Create+an+Amazon+RDS+Instance (last modified on Mar 25, 2019)

It has detailed instructions on how to configure an RDS instance so that it can be used with a WHM MySQL Profile.

Note 1: cPanel & WHM currently only supports connections to MySQL® 5.7.

Note 2: This only works on cPanel version 80 and up.

Comment: This link is not available anymore.